# How to force a excel user of a shared workbook to enable Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a shared workbook on a organisation's file server which has Login code in VBA. Once user logs in, he sees only the sheets which allowed for him. But it works only when user has already enabled macros. Otherwise he can see presently opened state of the workbook logged in by other user which is not desirable.

Now how can I force every user on the network to enable the macros when he opens my excel file ?

Comment: Due to the danger of VBA macros, they SHOULD be disabled in any corporate, government, public and/or shared computer. So you should NOT force people to enable macros.

Comment: Try to check if this link is helpful: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-excel-macros/

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented a solution, where I hid (in vba you can deep-hide sheets using xlVeryHidden, where they can't be viewed from the regular unhide menu) the sheets that I wanted to hide, then unhid a start page which said, in order to proceed, you must enable macros, which on enabling it, would hide that start screen, and unhide the other sheets.

This hiding was accomplished on-close of sheet, so you would need to process the macro in advance.

(Disclaimer: I am not sure how hiding sheets works with a shared workbook, but the solution might be along these lines)

Comment: I have implemented this. But when one person has already opened it, then other user with macros disabled opens it, he can see the first person's private sheets until he enables macros (because my workbook has private sheets for different users. I have deep hid every sheet other than his private sheet through user id & pwd system)

Comment: I don't see any way to prevent that if macros can be disabled... Maybe someone has a solution